# Como eu posso fazer este boxplot através do ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico

Preciso criar um gráfico usando o ggplot, mas só consegui criar ele usando o R base.

É uma pesquisa que estou fazendo. A pontuação das variáveis vai de 0 a 100.

Esse é o boxplot que eu criei usando o R Base:
[image: Esse é o boxplot que eu criei usando o R Base]

```
#Meus dados são mais ou menos assim:
Genero <- c("Homem", "Homem", "Mulher", "Mulher", "Homem", "Mulher", "Mulher", "Homem", "Mulher", "Homem")
V1 <- c(85, 100, 80, 70, 85, 85, 80, 70, 100, 80)
V2 <- c(92, 92, 84, 78, 80, 94, 100, 94, 100, 94)
V3 <- c(86, 80, 60, 53, 80, 73, 80, 73, 86, 93)
V4 <- c(80, 70, 20, 40, 60, 20, 100, 40, 60, 20)
V5 <- c(100, 90, 100, 80, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100)
boxplot(Dados$V1, Dados$V2, Dados$V3,  Dados$V4, Dados$V5, data = Dados, 
    horizontal = F, main = NULL, ylab = NULL, names = c("Sexismo", "LGBTfobia", "AmbUniver", "GenSexEns", "Valores"),
    col = c("darkred", "darkolivegreen4", "yellow3", "purple4", "darkorange3"), 
    cex.lab = 1.9, cex.axis = 2.7, cex = 1.5, cex.main = 2.8, lwd = 3, lty = "solid", bty = 7)
```

Como eu posso fazer isso usando o ggplot? Eu não consegui, porque não consigo colocar os V no eixo x, como faço com o boxplot no R base. E como eu poderia fazer, no ggplot, para colocar lado a lado homens e mulheres, sendo que também são componentes da mesma variável "Genero"?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 2):

```
#Pacotes
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

#Criar data.frame
df <-
  tibble(
    Genero,
    V1,
    V2,
    V3,
    V4,
    V5
  ) %>% 
  #Pivota dados para deixar todos os valores em um única coluna
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("V"))

#Vetor auxiliar de cores do boxplor
cores_boxplot <- c("darkred", "darkolivegreen4", "yellow3", "purple4", "darkorange3") 
#Vetor auxiliar para os rótulos do eixo x
nomes_x <- c("Sexismo", "LGBTfobia", "AmbUniver", "GenSexEns", "Valores")

df %>% 
  # Definição das variáveis que estarão nos respectivos eixos
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y= value))+
  #Adiciona o boxplot como geometria para o gráfico e omiti a legenda
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = name),show.legend = FALSE)+
  #Adiciona as cores no preenchimento do boxplot
  scale_fill_manual(values = cores_boxplot)+
  #Adiciona os nomes no eixo x
  scale_x_discrete(labels = nomes_x)+
  #Remove grid de apoio
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá, Vinícius. Embora a sua reposta esteja correta, seria interessante expandi-la, explicando o que foi feito em cada passo.

Answer (score 0):

Eis dois gráficos, o primeiro como o da pergunta e o segundo separado por `Genero`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dados, aes(name, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_boxplot(show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cores) +
  theme_classic()

ggplot(dados, aes(Genero, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = nomes, values = cores) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

---

### Dados

Os dados da pergunta com dois novos vetores, `nomes` e `cores` são

```
Genero <- c("Homem", "Homem", "Mulher", "Mulher", "Homem", "Mulher", "Mulher", "Homem", "Mulher", "Homem")
V1 <- c(85, 100, 80, 70, 85, 85, 80, 70, 100, 80)
V2 <- c(92, 92, 84, 78, 80, 94, 100, 94, 100, 94)
V3 <- c(86, 80, 60, 53, 80, 73, 80, 73, 86, 93)
V4 <- c(80, 70, 20, 40, 60, 20, 100, 40, 60, 20)
V5 <- c(100, 90, 100, 80, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100)
nomes <- c("Sexismo", "LGBTfobia", "AmbUniver", "GenSexEns", "Valores")
cores <- c("darkred", "darkolivegreen4", "yellow3", "purple4", "darkorange3")
```

Tal como os dados são apresentados na pergunta, creio que uma forma de ir buscar todos os vetores `V*` com `mget` e reformatar os dados para o formato longo pode ser a seguinte.
Não é necessário carregar os pacotes `dplyr` e `tidyr` para só usar funções desses pacotes uma vez.

```
mget(ls(pattern = "^V", envir = .GlobalEnv), envir = .GlobalEnv) |> 
  as.data.frame(col.names = nomes) |> 
  cbind(Genero) |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -Genero) |>
  dplyr::mutate(name = factor(name, levels = nomes)) -> dados

head(dados)  
## A tibble: 6 x 3
#  Genero name      value
#  <chr>  <fct>     <dbl>
#1 Homem  Sexismo      85
#2 Homem  LGBTfobia    92
#3 Homem  AmbUniver    86
#4 Homem  GenSexEns    80
#5 Homem  Valores     100
#6 Homem  Sexismo     100
```